# Переноситься каждое слово при абсолютном позиционировании

Tags: javascript, css, css3, frontend

1. Почему так происходит?
2. Как решить (*желательно без JS*) эту проблему, при условии что позиционирование должно остаться=)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>баг переносов</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="position: absolute;">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 107; cursor: default; ">
      <div style="position: relative; width: auto; left: 0; top: 0; ">
        <div>
          <span class="time">10.12.2011 | user<br>много много текста который по сути переноситься не должен<br><br></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ну так по всему контенту блока заполняются, ожидаемо. Скажите лучше как вам надо чтобы было

Comment: дайте блоку класс, например <div style="position: absolute;" class = 'container'>, а потом этому классу дайте ширину   .container{width: 500px;}. И всё.

Answer (score 0):

div с `position: absolute` не может быть родителем для блока `position: relative` 
 Этот баг переносов решается так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <title>баг переносов</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div>
            <div style="position: absolute; width: auto; left: 0; top: 0; ">
                <div>
                    <span class="time">10.12.2011 | user<br>много много текста который по сути переноситься не
                        должен<br><br></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```